# What is the difference between finding confit, and exp(confit)

Tags: r

The professor what is doing an example where he calculated the confit of a data set, and then did exp(confit), my question is what is the difference between those two?

Comment: I gather he was translating the confidence interval that was expressed as a log back to the original values by using the `exp()`onential function. That's a wild guess though considering I have no context. This isn't really a programming question that is in scope here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: so when we use confit, that will give us the 95% confidence interval, and when we use exp(confit), we get our values back?

Comment: No, `confint()` will always give a 95% CI by default. But the 95% CI will be in whatever scale the data is. I am guessing your teacher did this calculation with data that had been `log()`-ed, so they needed to `exp()` it afterwards to get back to the original values.